# Strange behaviour of Laravel Package binding - ModelNotFoundException when model exists and binding is set

Tags: laravel, phpunit, model-binding

I recently started to test my new api in Laravel Phpunit for book management, but when I wanted to update the book with id of created book like that:

```php
        $this->actingAs($user = factory(User::class)->create(), 'api');
        $user->givePermissionTo('manage books');
        $this->postJson('api/v1/books', $this->validData());
        $book = Book::first();


        $response = $this->putJson('api/v1/books/1', $this->validData())
```

I get this error

```
No query results for model [Custom\Book\Models\Book] 1, abcde, 9788055646916, 255, long_description, short_description, 2020-11-11T22:46:00.000000Z, 2020-11-11T22:46:00.000000Z
```

When i put there id of non-existing model I got a little different message

```
No query results for model [Custom\Book\Models\Book] 2
```

Mainly I don't understand, why it tries to bind whole object when I insert only id.

Model, controller and routes for book managing are in custom package and routes have api middleware set.

My controller method:

```
public function update(UpdateBookFormRequest $request, Book $book)
    {
        dump('kniha');
        dd($book);
        return (new BookService())->update($book, $request->validated());
    }
```

My routes

```
Route::resource('books', BookController::class)->only('store', 'update', 'destroy')->middleware('can:manage books');
```

My route service provider:

```
public function registerRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api'],
            function ($router) {
            require  __DIR__ . '/../routes.php';
        });
    }
```

What makes it even more strange is, when I call show method

```
$this->getJson('api/v1/books/1');
```

[I am able to bind Book model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z405W.png)

Sorry for my english.

Comment: can you show your controller code, It appears that you are querying for a book by a json objectand not simply by id

Comment: I just edited my question with using of code blocks, so its more readable, i think.